# Configure Bigquery Streaming retry time

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, streaming

When we connected to big query to stream data into the table, we occassionally faces this issue

> c.g.c.bigquery.storage.v1.StreamWriter   : Retriable error
> com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException:
> io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: Network closed for
> unknown reason received, retry count 1, millis left to retry 300000

and everything comes to a stop (probably it will recover after 5 minutes, I havent waited long enough to verify that). If we are restarting the streaming java app, everything will be back to normal.  300,000 milliseconds is equal to 5 minutes, which is like eternity. Is there anyway we can configure this to a lower number, say 1 second

Our code is wholesale copied from this https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquerystorage/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquerystorage/WriteToDefaultStream.java if that helps

Comment: Maybe you can solve your issue by using `timeout`.Let me know if this helps you or not?

Comment: Can you post the above comment in English?

Comment: Which timeout are you talking about Kiran?

Comment: You can specify [BigQuerysetting](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquerystorage/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWriteSettings) while creating the [BigQueryWriteClient](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigquerystorage/latest/com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWriteClient#com_google_cloud_bigquery_storage_v1_BigQueryWriteClient_create_com_google_cloud_bigquery_storage_v1_BigQueryWriteSettings_).